# Most Efficient Language to Write a Password Generator In

Tags: security, penetration-testing

If I wanted to write a program that generated all possible passwords using alphanumeric characters and wrote the output to a file, what language would would be best suited for writing something like that, for the purpose of penetration testing?

Edit: I already know C, C++, Java, javascript, python, ruby, HTML, CSS, and objective-c. I just have trouble identifying what language is better for solving which problems.

Comment: Any language mainstream programming language that you know should suffice. Which is .. none, guessing from this question :( [Protip: working >> "most efficient"]

Comment: Well, I know C, C++, javascript, html, css, python, ruby, x86 assembly, java, and objective-c. So yeah, not the case.

Comment: Well, I can pretty much rule out html and css, but apart from that those others should all work. Have fun!

Comment: efficient for performance, efficient from a space taken to write/understand? The task is trivial enough that any ham-fisted C/C++ implementation would be pretty performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to generate random passwords, but kind of a rainbow table without the need of hashes, you might just want to generate and 'increment' char sequences of certain lengths during the brute force test, like aaaa, aaab, aaac, ... You'd use the language, in which that test is written.

Comment: Would you mind linking me to a resource on rainbow tables? I've heard of them before but I've never had a chance to dive into them.

Comment: Wow you are just a charmer tonight @pst. I'm just asking if he has anything he'd recommend. No need to get your knickers in a twist.

Comment: @shadow: I guess, you don't want to find a valid password for a given hash, but just want to try plaintext passwords in a login form, for example, thus above answer. If so, a rainbow table might be less useful than a good dictionary attack. Either way, this may be something to start with: http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/ . Note that most online databases get closed often.

Answer (score 1):

Without sounding pedantic, here are a few things to consider :

What's this "efficiency" thing you're talking about? How do you measure it?

Are you sure it is connected to the language you write the program in?

Third, you realize that there are a very, very large range of possible passwords for most alphabets and lengths above, say, 6 or 7 chars? Are you sure this is the solution you need?

Fourth, aren't any solutions out there which already solve your problem?

---

More to the point: instead of choosing a language suited to the problem domain, consider choosing one which *you* are more experienced. But do check if your approach is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written any number of ways.  If I recall correctly, Python had a relatively simple structure for loops and writing to a file.  Although, so does C....

So pick a language you want to learn, and dive in.